# Как сверстать стрелку с тенью?

Tags: html, css

Собственно, подскажите пожалуйста, как сверстать такой элемент, чтобы он был с тенью?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я пытался делать вот так,

```css
.box {
width: 300px;
height: 70px;
background-color: #a6202e;
position: relative;
}
.box:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: -20px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 150px solid transparent;
  border-right: 150px solid transparent;
  border-top: 20px solid #a6202e;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 10px 13px -4px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 10px 13px -4px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
box-shadow: 0px 10px 13px -4px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
```

но всё равно он не получается таким как на картинке, у меня углы острые и нет тени, а ещё на самом треугольнике есть бордер.

Очень надеюсь на помощь и советы. Может стрелку можно сделать другим способом, кроме бордера ?

Answer (score 0):

Такие задачи желательно делать в фотошопе, после вставлять картинку на сайт, через `CSS` идеальный результат трудно получить, но приведу пример как можно реализовать на `CSS` (можно по эксперементировать на примере)

```css
#trig {
position: relative;
text-align: center;
padding: 9px;
margin: 60px auto;
height: 188px;
width: 200px;
}

#trig:before {
     content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 51%;
    background: red;
    -webkit-transform: skew(0deg, 20deg);
    -moz-transform: skew(0deg, 20deg);
    -ms-transform: skew(0deg, 20deg);
    -o-transform: skew(0deg, 20deg);
    transform: skew(0deg, 20deg);
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 33px 1px #999;
}
#trig:after {
     content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 50%;
    background: red;
    -webkit-transform: skew(0deg, -20deg);
    -moz-transform: skew(0deg, -20deg);
    -ms-transform: skew(0deg, -20deg);
    -o-transform: skew(0deg, -20deg);
    transform: skew(0deg, -20deg);
    box-shadow: 8px 9px 15px -2px #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div id="trig"></div>
```